# JSDoc + Mongoose : how to document Mongoose models?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jsdoc, mongoose-schema

I have `Mongoose` **schema** and a **model**:

```
var MyClientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fist_name: {
        type: String
    },
    phone_number: {
        type: String
    }
});

var MyClient = mongoose.model('MyClient', MyClientSchema);
```

**How should I document (using JSDoc) `MyClient` and/or `MyClientSchema` to get tab-completion and type suggestions from `WebStorm`** for both methods inherited from `mongoose.model` like `remove, findOne, find` - and inherited from schema - like `phone_number and first_name` ?

Answer (score 7):

I found `@class` (or its synonym `@constructor`) works for schema properties:

```
/**
 * @class MyClient
 */
var MyClientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fist_name: {
        type: String
    },
    phone_number: {
        type: String
    }
});

var MyClient = mongoose.model('MyClient', MyClientSchema);
```

The `@alias` works for methods declared the old way:

```
/**
 * @alias MyClient.prototype.getDescription
 */
MyClientSchema.method('getDescription', function () {
    return this.first_name + " " + this.phone_number;
});
```

However, you can mark all methods as part of `MyClient` **at once** if you use the new way of declaring methods:

```
/**
 * @class MyClient
 * @mixes {MyClientSchema.methods}
 */
var MyClientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ ...

/** @mixin */
MyClientSchema.methods;

MyClientSchema.methods.getDescription = function () {
    return this.first_name + " " + this.phone_number;
};
```

All the above tested in latest WebStorm version (2018.2). It works.

Things which do not work:

- Mongoose built-in methods like `.find()` or `.save()`
- The `.methods` syntax highlight works but code completion doesn't.

Updates are welcome!

Comment: Did this work for you in second file that imported MyClient. Was there any additional tags needed for this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Although it might not fit your specific requirement, this jet brains tutorial in the official documentation explains most of what you need

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/creating-jsdoc-comments.html

for example,

```
/**
 * MyClientSchema schema
 * @constructor MyClient
 */

var MyClientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        fist_name: {
            type: String
        },
        phone_number: {
            type: String
        }
    });
```

and the following js might be a guide foe you to do almost everything you need

http://nagyv.github.io/estisia-wall/models.js.html

Comment: Great reply. How are you handling validators used by the model?

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked as simple as:

```js
var MyClientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fist_name: {
        type: String
    },
    phone_number: {
        type: String
    }
});

var MyClient = mongoose.model('MyClient', MyClientSchema);

/**
 * @typedef {typeof MyClient} MyClientModel
 * @typedef {typeof MyClient.schema.obj} Client
 */

/**
 * @param {Client} client A MyClient document
 */
function (client) {
    client.[<here you get a suggestion for first_name>]
}
```

With the important note that you will not get `phone_number and first_name` from the schema's type but from the type of `MyClient.schema.obj` which defines a document.

Answer (score 1):

After years of searching for a solution to this, I have found it!

I guess JSDoc has been improving to include many more features from TS, making this possible, but you can reference types of properties of types, allowing you to do something like this:

```js
/**
 * @type {Parameters<Parameters<import('../models/userModel')["create"]>["1"]>["1"]}
 */
const user = {};
```

That is, it gets the `Parameters` of the `create` function on the `User` class prototype from `userModel.js` (which, `User` is a Mongoose model), the first parameter is the document inserted, but it is typed as `unknown` so... this necessitates the workaround of getting the `Parameters` of the callback (which is the second parameter of `create`), the first parameter of which is an `error`, so you need the second parameter, which is the type of the model!

You can make your life simple by typedeffing this:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Parameters<Parameters<T["create"]>["1"]>["1"]} ModelType<T>
 * @extends {import('mongoose').Model} This is probably unnecessary
 * @template T
 */
```

Then:
[image]