# JSDocs for Mongoose Schemas, including the implicit _id field

Tags: javascript, mongoose, webstorm, jsdoc

I want to be able to have JSDoc understand Mongoose Schemas so I can use the types in `@param`, `@returns`, and `@type`. I managed to achieve that using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915195/jsdoc-mongoose-how-to-document-mongoose-models). This works great:

```
/**
 * @class TheModel
 */
const theSchema = new Schema({
    . . .
});
```

The problem is, we left the `_id` off the schemas because they're implicit, but this means JSDoc doesn't know about them, and gives warnings if you try to access `_id` on a document.

How can I tell JSDoc about the extra `_id` field that it should include, despite it not being on the schema?

I tried creating a `@mixin MongooseModel` with `@property` for `_id`, and then changing my docs to:

```
/**
 * @class TheModel
 * @mixes MongooseModel
 */
const theSchema = new Schema({
    . . .
});
```

And along a similar vein, I tried creating a `@interface` with an `_id` field, and then adding `@implements` to the schema docs. Neither works. Webstorm does not give suggestions for `_id`.

I would prefer not to add a `_id` field to the schema since that requires the `_id` to be included when creating documents.

---

WebStorm 2023.1.2